# when i write MS SQL full text search query for return all matches, then it give me not correct output

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, contains, freetext, formsof

this is my query:-

```sql
select * from dbo.zones where freetext(name, 'test');
 select * from dbo.zones where contains(name, 'formsof(INFLECTIONAL, test)');
```

this give me result of- test, testing, tested

```sql
Select * from dbo.zones where contains(name, 'test');
```

this query only give me test result.

I am trying to get record which have "test" string like, "this is a test case".

so my query needs to find "test" string in "this is a test case" values also.

suppose i have a string in db column like "this is new generation", then i write a query like-

**select * from dbo.zones where contains(name, 'formsof(INFLECTIONAL, gen)');**

then this query not returning result of "this is new generation",
i need that if i pass "gen" for searching then this give above result

Comment: [From the docs for `CONTAINS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) "<simple_term> Specifies a match for an exact word or a phrase" It's doing exactly what it's supposed to do. What's wrong with using `INFLECTIONAL`?

Comment: select * from dbo.zones where contains(name, 'formsof(INFLECTIONAL, test)');

i also use INFLECTIONAL, but it gives me the result where only single "test" string exist, 
i need this result- "this is test case" in output, above query not finding "test" in middle of any string.. 
suppose i have a string in db column like "this is new generation", then i write a query like-  select * from dbo.zones where contains(name, 'formsof(INFLECTIONAL, gen)'); then this query not returning result of "this is new generation", i need that if i pass "gen" for searching then this give above result..

Comment: You can do a prefix search `CONTAINS(name, 'test*')` but really Full-Text is not designed for wildcard search, more for synonym search. You need `LIKE` instead

Comment: select * from  dbo.zones   where contains(name, 'test*');

no this is not returning, "hiitestmyside" as a result, this only returns where single "test" exist.

Comment: Obviously not, it's a *prefix* search so it needs to be the beginning of the string. It will find `testmyside`. If you want full wildcard search you are using the wrong tool